# Unable to see PnP webparts in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

[image]

In chrome, my test user is unable to see the pnp-search webparts. Other webparts are showing correctly. Only the PnP webparts are showing the same error always. And for Admin the PnP webparts are visible after a hard refresh else the same error.
I tried clearing the cache but no change.

But in Edge both of them can see the pnp webparts correctly.No need to refresh all are working fine.

Is there any permission i need to give to access the pnp-webparts

Please anyone help if you are aware of the cause.